# handle jquery event bubbling on table cell hover

Tags: jquery, events, event-bubbling

I have just started on event bubbling in jQuery so my understanding is very limited. I have a requirement to handle all the events that happen on the html table (grid) row/cells on parent container level. Example: 
1. when the user click on a row, I want instead of binding click event to each  I bind it to the parent . 
2. when user hover over a cell, I want to show the tooltip i.e. need to set the title attribute to the text element of the cell. I need to bubble this event too.

I am able to solve the first part of my requirement. Here is the code for part 1 (jsFiddle added below):

```
$('#grid').click(function(evt) {
    var row = $(evt.target).parent('tr'); // Get the parent row
    var cell= $(evt.target); //Get the cell
    alert('Row data: ' + row.text());
    alert('Cell data: ' + cell.text());
});
```

I thought it would be simple to implement hover too. But I am not able to trap the individual cell value. Here is my sample code in fiddle [jsFiddle: sample code to bubble the event on cell hover](http://jsfiddle.net/3xp7Q/2/)

also, I noticed that I see alert twice on hover. I guess it is raising the event once for the cell and then for the row/table. Not sure?

Comment: Can't answer your question entirely but you want `mouseover` instead of `hover`.

Comment: @sachleen, changing it to mouseover does show the cell value but first it shows the entire table content and then it shows the cell value. Can I restrict it to just return the cell value?

Comment: That's because it hovers over the table as well. You want to do what joshatjben suggested but here's a working version of it: http://jsfiddle.net/3xp7Q/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`$.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to achieve this like following. As of jQuery 1.7 all calls to `.live()`, `.bind()`, '.delegate()' uses `.on()` under the hood. And `.on` binds the event only on `#grid` and intercept the event on that element and then check if the target mactches the second selector. If so then execute the function.

```
$('#grid').on('mouseenter','td', function(){
       console.log($(this).text());
   });​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/4HzL4/)

Comment: Wow I never noticed the `Firebug Lite` check box. So convenient! Don't have to mess with positioning the Chrome dev tools window so it doesn't get in the way.

Comment: @sachleen, yeah it's very handy. But only available when you select `jQuery (edge)` as the library/framework.

Comment: Same question, how is this implementation different than the one I posted? I mean, how is click event with delegate different from event bubbling code that I have in original post? I too like jQuery edge - thanks for showing that to us :)

Comment: Ah that's why! Not to start an unrelated thread here, but is there a way to select these as default options in new jsfiddles?

Comment: @sachleen, you are hijacking the thread :) but it's ok. I am learning this too.

Comment: @kuul13 your code happens on the table's `hover` event. This code happens when your mouse enters a `td`. This is what solves your issue where it displays the entire table data when moving from one column to another.

Comment: @sachleen, I am not sure if there is any such option.

Comment: @sachleen, I understand that. But I wanted to know how conceptually the delegate code for say 'click' event (not talking about hover at this time) differ from my code above (event bubbling)?